# Using external image as drawable resource

Tags: java, android, android-resources, android-external-storage

So I have an image saved on the external SD-Card. Now, I want to use that image as a resource in my project. (I want to use the image located at the specific path instead of R.drawable.image).

It would be also great, if there was a way to kinda "add" the image to the resources (and not just use it),  that the image gets something like a resourceID like the ones in R.drawable got.

But basically I just want to display an external image in an imageView.

Answer (score 2):

First you will need read external storage permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

then,

```
String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +"directoryName/imageName.png";
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code.

```
File file = new File("put your bitmap address here");
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** add any files to the app package (apk file) in runtime. If you want the image in your drawable folder, you should add it before packaging.

```
String path = "path-to-image";
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap); //if you want a drawable
```